# Populate a series of textboxes with random values in Access - run time error 3021 No current record

Tags: for-loop, ms-access, vba, runtime-error, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to populate a series of textboxes with random value from a column.
i get the first textbox filled then it returns run time error 3021 - no current record.
i checked the values and the record I'm trying to retrieve doesn't exceed recordcount for the table.
Debug colours rs.move randomrecord.

```
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim recordCount As Long
    Dim randomRecord As Long

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM besede")
    rs.MoveLast
    rs.MoveFirst
    recordCount = rs.recordCount - 1
    MsgBox recordCount
    Randomize
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 10
       randomRecord = Int((recordCount) * Rnd)
       rs.Move randomRecord
       Controls("t" & i).SetFocus
       Controls("t" & i) = rs!test
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are moving the cursor from the current position, so eventually you are trying to read a record at the end of the recordset. Use

`rs.MoveFirst` before `rs.Move randomRecord`

to move from the beginning of the recordset.

Check [Office Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191697(v=office.15).aspx) for more background information on `Recordset.Move`.